# How to call .NET DLL from Inno Setup using DNNE?

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have previously successfully used [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) and [DllExport](https://github.com/3F/DllExport) to use .NET DLL files with Inno Setup.

However now I am trying to get it to work with [DNNE](https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE).

I have the following C# code targeting x86

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DNNE" Version="1.0.31" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DNNETest
{
    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "MessageBox",
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal static extern int MsgBox(
            IntPtr hWnd, string lpText, string lpCaption, uint uType);
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
        public static void Test()
        {
            _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, "Hello from C#", ":)", 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I made a small console app to verify the exported code is working correctly:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

NE.Test();

public static class NE
{
    [DllImport("DNNETestNE", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public extern static void Test();
}
```

Works OK!

---

Now I try to move it to Inno Setup:

```
[Files]
Source: Files\Dotnet\DNNETest.deps.json; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Files\Dotnet\DNNETest.dll; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Files\Dotnet\DNNETest.runtimeconfig.json; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Files\Dotnet\DNNETestNE.dll; Flags: dontcopy
```

```pascal
procedure Test();
external 'Test@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure InitializeDotnet;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\DNNETest.deps.json');
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\DNNETest.dll');
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\DNNETest.runtimeconfig.json');
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll');
  Test();
end;
```

Will crash with `Could not call proc`

I also tried

```pascal
external 'Test@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll,DNNETest.dll stdcall delayload loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

Played around with combinations of `AnyCPU`, `x86`, `x64` but to no avail

But same error

I am unsure what else I can try, since these steps were working ok with the other DllImport packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work because

> The compiler also decorates C functions that use the __stdcall calling convention with an underscore (_) prefix and a suffix composed of the at sign (@) followed by the number of bytes (in decimal) in the argument list.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-170

The quick fix is to use `cdecl` instead of `stdcall` on both C# and Pascal definitions

If you really want to use `stdcall`, keep reading...

---

To fix it:
Add this line to `<PropertyGroup>`

```xml
<DnneWindowsExportsDef>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\DnneWindowsExports.def</DnneWindowsExportsDef>
```

Add the following:

```
EXPORTS
   Test=Test
```

Replace `Test` with the function you want to export

---

I made a small console app, which will generate this file: Just add a reference to your project and replace the classname in `typeof` to one with your exports.

```
using DNNETest;
using System.Text;

var names = typeof(NativeExports).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();

var output = new StringBuilder();
output.AppendLine("EXPORTS");

foreach (var name in names)
{
    output.AppendLine($"\t{name}={name}");
}

var result = output.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
File.WriteAllText(@"SomeLocation\DnneWindowsExports.def", result);
```

---

I made the following example to show it's working

```
public static class NativeExports
{
    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static void Test()
    {
        _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, nameof(Test), "C#", 0);
    }

    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static void SendInt(int value)
    {
        _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, $"{nameof(SendInt)}: {value}", "C#", 0);
    }

    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static void SendString(IntPtr value)
    {
        var message = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(value);
        _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, $"{nameof(SendString)}: {message}", "C#", 0);
    }

    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static unsafe void ReturnString(IntPtr value, IntPtr* result)
    {
        var message = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(value);

        var returnString = new string(message.Reverse().ToArray());
        _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, $"{nameof(ReturnString)}: {message} => {returnString}", "C#", 0);

        *result = Marshal.StringToBSTR(returnString);
    }

    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static int ReturnInt(int input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public delegate bool ExpandConstantDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string input, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string output);
    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
    public static void CallExpandConstantCallback(IntPtr callbackPtr)
    {
        var ExpandConstant = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ExpandConstantDelegate>(callbackPtr);

        var constant = "{tmp}";
        ExpandConstant(constant, out var result);

        _ = NativeMethods.MsgBox(IntPtr.Zero, $"{nameof(ExpandConstant)}({constant}) => {result}", "C#", 0);
    }
}
```

```pascal
procedure Test();
external 'Test@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure SendInt(value: Integer);
external 'SendInt@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure SendString(value: string);
external 'SendString@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure ReturnString(value: string; out outValue: WideString);
external 'ReturnString@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

function ReturnInt(value: Integer) : Integer;
external 'ReturnInt@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure ExpandConstantWrapper(const toExpandString: string; out expandedString: WideString);
begin
  expandedString := ExpandConstant(toExpandString);
end;

procedure CallExpandConstantCallback(callback: Longword);
external 'CallExpandConstantCallback@{tmp}\DNNETestNE.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure InitializeDotnet;
var
  outString: WideString;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFiles('{tmp}\DNNETest*');
  Test();
  SendInt(1234);
  SendString('Hello World');
  ReturnString('ReverseMe!', outString);
  MessageBox(outString, 0);
  MessageBox(IntToStr(ReturnInt(4321)), 0);
  CallExpandConstantCallback(CreateCallback(@ExpandConstantWrapper));
end;
```